# How Spring and Hibernate with JPA enabled enterprise applications can be helpful to the business?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I was asked this question in an interview. My answer was as follows.

Spring makes Java/J2EE development easier, more efficient and more productive. Hibernate helps to get rid of complex and tedious data access code and reap the benefits of object oriented principles.

By blending spring with hibernate we can create scalable, robust, maintainable and database independent enterprise applications at lightning speed thus reduce time to market.

I am not satisfied with my answer as interviewer was expecting answer in business perspective and my answer was far away and has technical details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the key points I'd say is cost (it's open source, which means no licensing fees), speed of application development (turnaround time from getting an idea to having a deliverable is much shorter compared to other frameworks), portability (you can move the application to any server and it will more likely than not just work out of the box), flexibility (making changes to business logic is quick and easy), maintainability (java has been around for a long time and probably will be around for much longer, finding developers to work on the project in the future won't be that difficult as it is when using legacy code), stability (since the architecture is build upon a stable platform, downtime should not be an issue), scalability (if the userbase grows rapidly, moving to a cloud environment is straight forward, no extra cost changing the application)

Answer (score 1):

If you agruee with Business Guyes you must use the terms:

- cost (total cost of owner ship)
- time to market
- productivity

All what you said was right, but you missed the business related conclution:

"Spring, Hibernate, ... help to develop applications faster and in a very porductive style, so the time to market is reduced. On the other hand Spring and Hibernate tend the programmer to produce more maintainable and tested code. This will reduce the cost to maintain the software and provide the posibility to enhance the application at realative low cost."

Answer (score 1):

spring  + hibernate framework with jpa is provided a productive application. Because the framework is divided in to the layer that's why the new programmer can easily understand and can change easily in to the enterprises project. spring framework provides the dependency injection that means no need for the manually creation of object through the new key word. while spring provide the object and only programmer focus on the used of object. And hibernate  is a orm framework which is fully rich in relation database. It used save/update/delete the data into the table by taking the java object only. It reduce the java code for the database connectivity and writing the sql query and much more . hibernate provide the methods for dml(data manipulation language) operations.

Answer (score 0):

the Spring is the ultimate framework, and the hibernate supoort of it is just amazing,
it help a lot,
security features, helpful in TDD programing,
unit test, integration testing etc.

it is very helpful in maintaining very bulky project very easily.

today most of the heavy projects managers prefer spring with hibernate

hope it is helpful to you

thanks